# Servlet example in the java web application

Tags: java, tomcat, maven

I'm new to java web application development, can you tell me, what am I doing wrong:
I have generated the web application using maven:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=webapp -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
```

I have put **HelloWorld.java** in the src.main.resources folder, here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet{ 
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
  HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException,IOException{
  response.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
  pw.println("<html>");
  pw.println("<head><title>Hello World</title></title>");
  pw.println("<body>");
  pw.println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
  pw.println("</body></html>");
  }
}
```

my **web.xml** from src.main.webapp.WEB-INF looks like:

```
!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
          "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
          "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

here is my **pom.xml**:

```
project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-webapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>my-webapp Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>my-webapp</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
            <server>mytomcat</server>
            <path>/my-app</path>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Then i type 
`mvn package tomcat:deploy` 
and on the link localhost:8080/web/HelloWorld -

```
HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class HelloWorld

type Exception report

message Error instantiating servlet class HelloWorld

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class HelloWorld    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)  org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)  org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Comment: What does the log file for the servlet container say ? That'll have the stack trace relating to your 500 error

Comment: #Satya, put what? HelloWorld.java? put in java.com.mycompany.app, like that? still the same..

Comment: #Brian Agnew, I just have edited the error log

Comment: FYI, to get this example to work I had to add the Servlet dependency <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have put HelloWorld.java in the src.main.resources folder

The java code should not be in `src/main/resources`, it should be in `src/main/java`.

Your `HelloWorld.java` has never been built and thus it cannot be found by tomcat. Your `war` file does not contain the `HelloWorld.class`.

Comment: Yes, now i have HelloWorld.class in the tomcat server WEB-INF folder, but still the same error

Comment: i figured it out, the point was to add com.mycompany.app.HelloWorld - path to the pom.xml file